# How do I use the predict function to return the probability of making 50k a year and add it as a categorical variable to my dataTestReduced dataframe?

Tags: r, data-science, computer-science

Here is the beginning of my code

```
library(car, quietly = TRUE)

dataTrain <- read.csv("~/Downloads/AdultsTrainDataset.csv", na.strings = "?")
dataTest <- read.csv("~/Downloads/AdultsTestDataset.csv",   na.strings = "?")

dataTrainNAremoval <- sum(is.na(dataTrain))
dataTestNAremoval <- sum(is.na(dataTest))

dataTrain <- na.omit(dataTrain)
dataTest <- na.omit(dataTest)

dataReduced <- dataTrain[dataTrain$race %in% c("Black", "White"),]
dataReduced[dataReduced$marital.status %in% c("Married-civ-spouse", "Married-AF-spouse"),"marital.status"] <- "married"
dataReduced[dataReduced$marital.status %in% c("Divorced", "Separated","Widowed","Married-spouse-absent"),"marital.status"] <- "pMarried"

dataReduced[dataReduced$education %in% c("11th","12th","1st-4th","5th-6th","7th-8th", "9th", "HS-grad","10th", "Preschool", "Some-college"), "education"] <- "less-than-Uni" 
dataReduced[dataReduced$education %in% c("Assoc-acdm","Assoc-voc", "Prof-school", "Bachelors"), "education"] <- "University"
dataReduced[dataReduced$education %in% c("Masters","Doctorate", "Prof-school"), "education"] <- "advancedDegree"

dataReduced$incomeNum <- dataReduced$income == ">50K"
```

Here is how I've created my classifier

```
dataToModel <- dataReduced[,c("sex","marital.status","race","education","incomeNum")]
theModel <- glm(formula = incomeNum ~ ., data = dataToModel, family = "binomial")
summary(theModel)
```

and I would like clarification on how I can use it to return the probability of making 50k a year and then transform it into a categorical variable to use in my dataTestReduced dataframe. I've tried the following but am unsure on what my newdata input should be.

```
probabilities <- predict(theModel, newdata =  , type = "response")
dataReduced$probabilities <- probabilities > "50k"
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of your data so others can help you. For example, if you run `dput(dataToModel)` and paste the output into your question, it would be easier to help you directly.

Comment: dput(dataToModel) returns far too much to paste. It just says either black and white for race a bunch of times as well as true or false a bunch of times (I'm assuming for whether the person makes more or less than 50k)

Comment: If it helps I can provide more of my coding rather than copy and paste a huge amount of words repeatedly

Comment: You can provide a subset of your data instead. For example `dataToModel %>% slice(1:100)` or `subset(dataToModel, incomeNum > 1000)`

Comment: First example returns an error that says "could not find function %>%" and the second one returns "0 rows"

Comment: Thats because the first command requires the `tidyverse` package. I'm guessing the second one is because you don't have data that fits that filter.

Answer (score 0):

#### Quick Example

I've used the `iris` dataset here to give you an idea of how `predict` normally works since you're having issues sharing your data. I think you have the order a bit backwards. First, fit the regression like so:

```
#### Fit Regression ####
fit <- lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width,
            iris)
```

Then create new data to predict with. In this case, I'm only adding one predictor variable as this is a simple regression:

```
#### Create New Data ####
new.data <- data.frame(Petal.Width = 2)
```

Finally you fit the new data with the old regression like so:

```
#### Predict Outcome With New Data  ####
predict(fit,
        newdata = new.data,
        type = "response")
```

#### Using Subsets of Data

In your case perhaps you are looking to fit data purely based off values that are greater than a certain level. You would likely do something like this:

```
#### Load Library ####
library(tidyverse) # for filtering/selecting

#### Create Filtered Data ####
new.data.2 <- iris %>% 
  filter(Petal.Width > 1) %>% 
  select(Petal.Width)

#### Fit Again ####
predict(fit,
        newdata = new.data.2,
        type = "response")
```

Which gives you your predicted values. Keep in mind it has already fit these specific values, so it isn't really giving you any new information, only a subset based on your filter:

```
       1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8 
4.205475 4.428469 4.428469 3.982481 4.428469 3.982481 4.651463 3.982481 
       9       10       11       12       13       14       15       16 
4.205475 4.428469 4.205475 3.982481 4.205475 4.428469 4.428469 3.536493 
      17       18       19       20       21       22       23       24 
5.097451 3.982481 4.428469 3.759487 3.982481 4.205475 4.205475 4.874457 
      25       26       27       28       29       30       31       32 
4.428469 3.536493 3.759487 4.651463 4.428469 4.651463 4.428469 3.982481 
      33       34       35       36       37       38       39       40 
3.982481 3.982481 3.759487 4.205475 3.759487 3.982481 3.759487 3.982481 
      41       42       43       44       45       46       47       48 
3.982481 3.536493 3.982481 6.658409 5.320445 5.766433 5.097451 5.989427 
      49       50       51       52       53       54       55       56 
5.766433 4.874457 5.097451 5.097451 6.658409 5.543439 5.320445 5.766433 
      57       58       59       60       61       62       63       64 
5.543439 6.435415 6.212421 5.097451 5.989427 6.212421 4.428469 6.212421 
      65       66       67       68       69       70       71       72 
5.543439 5.543439 5.097451 5.766433 5.097451 5.097451 5.097451 5.766433 
      73       74       75       76       77       78       79       80 
4.651463 5.320445 5.543439 5.989427 4.428469 4.205475 6.212421 6.435415 
      81       82       83       84       85       86       87       88 
5.097451 5.097451 5.766433 6.435415 6.212421 5.320445 6.212421 6.658409 
      89       90       91       92       93 
6.212421 5.320445 5.543439 6.212421 5.097451
```